# How to print the first 5 items on my sorted list in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```py
file = open('Leaderboard.csv','r')
    csv1= csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    sort = sorted(csv1, key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)
    for eachline in sort:
        print (eachline)
```

I am trying to print the **first 5 items** of this sorted list. Right now the code prints the whole Leaderboard. Just to inform you I am quite new to python.

Here is my current leaderboard:

```
Hallo,7
Ahmad,18
Jake,20
Yoyo,16
Longa,9
Daniel,14
Nope,31
Jai,9
Noli,18
Jenna,26
noij,23
Kanoli,17
Yeet,8
Kasky,14
Gonzalez,17
Hiho,7
Yayeet,19
Frenzo,30
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the first `n` elements in a list `l` you can slice it: `l[:n]`.

So in this case you'd write `for eachline in sort[:5]:`